# Parse JSON string inside another JSON

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have some JSON that contains another JSON object inside **in a form of a string** (note quotes around the `"jsonString"` value):

```
{
  "jsonString":"{\"someKey\": \"Some value\"}"
}
```

I know that if `"jsonString"` didn't have quotes around its value, I would do something like this:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Something: Decodable {
  struct SomethingElse: Decodable {
    let someKey: String
  }
  let jsonString: SomethingElse
}

let jsonData = """
               {
                 "jsonString":"{\"someKey\": \"Some value\"}"
               }
               """.data(using: .utf8)!
let something = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Something.self, from: jsonData)
```

But it doesn't work for my case. It doesn't work even if I treat `"jsonString"` as a `String` and do something like this:

```swift
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: SomethingKey.self)

  let jsonStringString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .jsonString)
  if let jsonStringData = jsonStringString.data(using: .utf8) {
    self.jsonString = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomethingElse.self, from: jsonStringData)
  } else {
    self.jsonString = SomethingElse(someKey: "")
  }
}
private enum SomethingKey: String, CodingKey {
  case jsonString
}
```

The error I'm experiencing is:

```
Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around line 2, column 18." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around line 2, column 18., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=20})))
```

However, all JSON validators I tried say that the JSON is valid and conforms to RFC 8259.

Swift doesn't let me to escape nested "{" and ”}" either.

---

The JSON format, unfortunately, is out of my control and I cannot alter it.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037604/parse-json-inside-another-json-string-in-swift4) question, which looks similar, but nothing there works. Answers are relevant only for regular nested JSON objects. Or I missed something.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON to my eyes!

Comment: The JSON should be `{"jsonString": "{\"someKey\": \"someValue\"}"}`, escpaing the double quotes inside the value `jsonString`. The given one isn't valid. In your custom `init(from decoder:)`, could you print the `let jsonString`?

Comment: The error is saying that the JSON isn't valid at all, not the `try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .jsonString)` part, the JSON Stringifieed with JSON.

Comment: @phuzi I updated the question, re-formatted a bit and complemented with some more details. JSON is valid.

Comment: @Larme I updated the question, re-formatted a bit and complemented with some more details. JSON is valid. `init(from decoder: Decoder)` is not even called, the error is thrown on the line `JSONDecoder().decode(Something.self, from: jsonData)`. Please try to paste my code snippet into Playground and you'll immediately see what I mean.

Comment: That's because in the `jsonData` you gave, it's badly created. it's either: `let jsonData = """--{"jsonString":"{\\"someKey\\": \\"Some value\\"}"}---""".data(using: .utf8)!` where "--" is a new line in the IDE, or `let jsonData = #"{"jsonString":"{\"someKey\": \"Some value\"}"}"#.data(using: .utf8)!` since when declaring a String, you still need to escape the backslash.

Comment: @Larme Genius! Both options worked as expected, thanks a lot! If you post your finding as an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted. ;)

Comment: (Another thing worth mentioning is that I didn't know I can't add line breaks inside that nested JSON string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that the whole JSON isn't valid, not just the `jsonString` value.

While it's true that (you can test it in online validator like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) for instance):

```
{
    "jsonString": "{\"someKey\": \"Some value\"}"
}
```

When declaring it as a String in Swift, you need to make sure that the backslashes are really present.

So it's:

```
let jsonString = """
{ "jsonString": "{\\"someKey\\": \\"Some value\\"}"}
"""
```

or

```
let jsonString = #"{"jsonString":"{\"someKey\": \"Some value\"}"}"#
```